# LINQ Query using if condition and && Operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller Method for Search

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string cno, string fname, string lname, string male, string female, string istateid, string icityid, string professionid, string educationid)
    {

        var db = new clubDataContext();
        var query = db.M_Registarions.Where((x=> x.M_ContactNo ==(cno??x.M_ContactNo) && x.M_Fname == (fname ?? x.M_Fname) && x.M_Lname==(lname ?? x.M_Lname) && x.M_Gender == (male??x.M_Gender));
        if(istateid != "")
        {
            int stateid1 = Convert.ToInt32(istateid);
             query = query.Where(x=> x.M_StatteId == stateid1);
        }
        if(icityid != "")
        {
            int cityid1 = Convert.ToInt32(icityid);
             query = query.Where(x=> x.M_CityId == cityid1);
        }
         if(professionid != "")
         {
            int professionid1 = Convert.ToInt32(professionid);
            query = query.Where(x=> x.P_id == professionid1);
         }
         if(educationid != "")
         {
         int educationid1 = Convert.ToInt32(educationid);
         query = query.Where(x=> x.P_id == educationid1);
         }
         if (!query.Any())
         {
             ViewBag.Count = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             var result = query.ToList();

             //var search_query = from p in db.M_Registarions where (x => x.M_Fname.Contains(fname ?? x.M_Fname) || x.M_Lname.Contains(lname ?? x.M_Lname)) select p;
             ViewBag.SearchResult = result;
             ViewBag.Count = 1;
         }
            return PartialView("SearchResult");
    }
```

Here I am using OR operation in cno, firstname and last name. I want to use &&(And) operation instead of ||(OR). But problem is I have to check for NULL or Space, that I have done in stateid, cityid , professionid and educationid. **So how to use if condition in first where? var query = db.M_Registration.Where(if{}) Like this?**

Comment: please could you be more specific on what you want? I mean, please post the linq query you want to reform. State exactly what you expect as a result. Thanks

Comment: In simple way, I want to know how to use if condition in first where clause. I have already mentioned LINQ query.

Comment: You mean here Where((x=> x.M_ContactNo ==(cno??x.M_ContactNo) && x.M_Fname == (fname ?? x.M_Fname) && x.M_Lname==(lname ?? x.M_Lname) && x.M_Gender == (male??x.M_Gender)); ? right?

Comment: Ya right, I want && operation instead of ||. And for that I have to check for null.

Comment: Yeah, but there you are already use && operator the c = a ?? b checks if a is not null and assigns it to c, otherwise b is assigned to c. Do you want to avoid ??

Comment: Yes, you are very correct. But problem is, cno giving me "" instead of null. So I need to check for "". That I have done in next query statement.

Comment: You mean something like `query = query.Where(x=> (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stateid1) ? String.Empty : x.M_StatteId) == (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stateid1) ? String.Empty : stateid1));`

Answer (score 0):

Use blocs {} and "return" to put a more complex expression

For example :

```
db.M_Registration.Where(p => 
                    {
                        if{ // my condition... }
                            return p.Name == name
                        else
                            return p.Name == ...
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string cno, string fname, string lname, string male, string female, string istateid, string icityid, string professionid, string educationid)
{

    var db = new clubDataContext();
    var query = db.M_Registarions.Where((x=> x.M_ContactNo ==(cno??x.M_ContactNo) && x.M_Fname == (fname ?? x.M_Fname) && x.M_Lname==(lname ?? x.M_Lname) && x.M_Gender == (male??x.M_Gender));
    if(IntValue(istateid).HasValue)
    {
         query = query.Where(x=> x.M_StatteId == IntValue(istateid).Value);
    }
    if(IntValue(icityid).HasValue)
    {
         query = query.Where(x=> x.M_CityId == IntValue(icityid).Value);
    }
     if(IntValue(professionid).HasValue)
     {
        query = query.Where(x=> x.P_id == IntValue(professionid).Value);
     }
     if(IntValue(educationid).HasValue)
     {
     query = query.Where(x=> x.P_id == IntValue(educationid).Value);
     }
     if (!query.Any())
     {
         ViewBag.Count = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         var result = query.ToList();

         //var search_query = from p in db.M_Registarions where (x => x.M_Fname.Contains(fname ?? x.M_Fname) || x.M_Lname.Contains(lname ?? x.M_Lname)) select p;
         ViewBag.SearchResult = result;
         ViewBag.Count = 1;
     }
        return PartialView("SearchResult");
}

    public int? IntValue(string input) 
    {
        int temp;

        if (int.TryParse(input, out temp)) 
        {
            return temp;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get the result you want and avoid having tons of ifs, by trying the following query:

```
var query =
        db.M_Registarions.Where(
            x =>
                x.M_ContactNo == (cno ?? x.M_ContactNo) && x.M_Fname == (fname ?? x.M_Fname)
                && x.M_Lname == (lname ?? x.M_Lname) && x.M_Gender == (male ?? x.M_Gender)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(istateid) || x.M_StatteId == Convert.ToInt32(istateid))
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(icityid) || x.M_CityId == Convert.ToInt32(icityid))
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(professionid) || x.P_id == Convert.ToInt32(professionid))
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(educationid) || x.P_id == Convert.ToInt32(educationid)));
```